# to retrieve information from dynamic divs with jquery and how to send this to the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm building a structure with dynamic DIVS using html and jquery, where the client reports a description for the div and then I put a number for the div and its description, that div is out of the form. and I need to retrieve all this information to send to a form.

**how can I retrieve all information from the div?**

**What is the best way to pass this information to the server?**

my idea was as follows, when I click on send then it reads all divs and retrieves the div id and its description, so I mount the structure my way example: 1div: description = 2div: description = 3div: description,
after I mount this structure I pass this data to an input type text that is as hidden in my page and is inside my form tags and then send, and on the server side I return this information to normal state, this is correct? but as I can read the information contained in my div

```js
$('#add').click(function(){
  
  var number = $('div.children').filter(function(idx){
          return $(this).text() != ""
      }).length;
  
  var newdiv = '';
  newdiv+='<div class="children">';
  newdiv+='  <b> Div '+(number+1)+' </b>';
  newdiv+='  <p>descript: this is div '+(number+1)+'</p>';
  newdiv+='</div>';
  
  $('#DivFather').append(newdiv);
  
  return false;
});

$('#send').click(function(){
  
  alert('id:div1-descript:this is div 1=id:div2-descript:this is div 2');
  return false;
});
```

```css
div div {
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  margin: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="DivFather">

  <div class="children">
    <b> Div 1 </b>
    <p>descript: this is div 1</p>
  </div>

</div>

<a href="" id="add" class="btn btn-primary"> Add Div </a>

<a href="" id="send" class="btn btn-primary"> Send form </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you have some information which you put into `DIVs`, then when the user clicks `SEND`, you read want to read teh `DIVs` and send them to a server like if they were `INPUTs` in a `form`.

1st) If you have the "raw" information beforehand which you put in the `DIV`, use that information instead of reading it again from the `div`.

One way of doing this is mantaining a javascript array with the information and setting the index of the array to the element the user clicks or selects. You can use a `data-id` attribute on the element (`data-id="1"`). When the element is clidcked you get the id using jQuery attr('data-id'). You could also set the id of the element or use a class that holds the id and search it from there, but the `data-` attribute comes in very handy for this.

2nd) To send the information see jQuery's `$.ajax()` or `$.POST()` which will let you do a post and send the information as multipart in the 'data' attribute.

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url : 'http://www.example.com',
            type : 'post',
            data : {
                dataField1 : 'some value',
                dataField2 : 'some value',
                dataField3 : 'some value',
                dataField4 : 'some value',
            },
            success : function( response, textStatus, jqXHR  ) {
                // In response you get what the server sends back

            },
            error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown ){
                //log to the browser console
                console.log(jqXHR);
            },
            beforeSend: function(jqXHR, settings ){
                //disable the send button after it is clicked
                jQuery("#sendButton").addClass( "disabled");
            },
            complete : function(jqXHR, textStatus ){
                //Enable send button when we are back
                jQuery("#sendButton").removeClass( "disabled");
            }
        });
```

Comment: right, but how can I read this information on the grid? do you think I should apply for each one a date? for example, data-id, data-disciption?

Comment: I editted my answer. I prefer to keep an array or an object to hold the information so as to separate presentation from logic. I also included an ajax example. There are many options for ajax I suggest you look into the docs in jQuery site to adjust to your needs, for example if you expect a json as a response.